# How can I build a condition based single query in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

[image]

```
<?php                                                             

$busno=3;                                                     
$busname = 'Bus3';                                            

$startdate='09/03/2017';                                      
$enddate='09/11/2017';                                        

$value1 = value_table::where('Start Date', $startdate)->get();
$value1 = value_table::where('End Date', $enddate)->get();
```

I want to check that the start date & end date should not conflict with any date in the table.

Is there any chance to check it with a single query?

Comment: use orWhere() after the first where() or chain the two where()s

Comment: Which version of Laravel you are using?

Comment: should not conflict? you mean there's no overlap in the durations between your start and end date and the start and end dates within the database or the database doesn't contain the same start and end dates?

Comment: @duong khang laravel 4

Comment: @apokryfos  start date & end date should not conflict with same date in database & it should not come in between the database start date & enddate

Answer (score 0):

```
$value1 = value_table::where('Start Date', $startdate)->where('End Date', $enddate)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this like:

```
$value1 = value_table::whereDate('Start Date', $startdate)
                     ->whereDate('End Date', $enddate)
                     ->get();
OR

$value1 = value_table::where('Start Date', $startdate)
                     ->orWhere('End Date', $enddate)
                     ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If you need to check if one pair of dates is not contained within another then do this:

```
$value = value_table::where('Start date',">=",$endDate)  //starts after your end date
                    ->orWhere('End date',"<=",$startDate) //Ends before the other start date
```

2) To check if a pair of dates is fully contained within another pair of dates do this:

```
$value = value_table::where('Start date',"<",$startDate)
                    ->where('End date',">",$endDate);
```

3) To check if a pair of dates is partially contained within another pair then do this:

```
$value = value_table::where(function ($q) {
        $q->where('Start date',"<",$startDate); 
        $q->where('End date',">", $startDate); //$startDate within 
})->orWhere(function ($q) {
        $q->where('Start date',"<",$endDate); 
        $q->where('End date',">", $endDate); //$endDate within 
});
```

Comment: $startdate = 08/27/2017 ; $enddate = 09/02/2017 ;
 if you check in my table image they should be a two conflict.
 $startdate & $enddate should come in between the two fields.
 i want to check this kind of function. is they possible to write in query

Comment: @Balaji So you want to get conflicts instead of non-conflicts?

Comment: it want to non-conflict, in above my comment i give the two date . if i check with my table , the date come in between two row date . if it come like that i want to conflict. it should show an error.

Comment: @Balaji Check the update. I think you need the 3rd solution